# Validating a contact form with javascript?

Tags: javascript, validation, loops, contacts

I have a contact form that I'm going to validate with JS. 
I want a function to loop through all the inputs and work out which one is the email by searching it for a '@' symbol, then assigning it to a variable to be handled later.

I've initialized variables for each input box and assigned them as values in the input array.
I've looped through them and checked them against a regular expression (a simple a-z letter check), just to make sure they've all had content inputted.

If they match the RegExp then I want them to be passed to a string search to look for an @ symbol to determine which one is the email input.

This is my code below but it's not working.
Can anyone tell me where i've gone wrong? 
Thanks!

```
 var emailaddress;
function find_email() {
        var name = document.getElementById("username");
        var email = document.getElementById("email");
        var msg = document.getElementById("messagecontent");
        var racenum = document.getElementById("racenum");
        var input = [name, email, racenum, msg];

        for (i = 0; i <= input.length; i++) {
            var standard_check = /[a-zA-Z0-9]/g;
            if (input[i].value.match(standard_check)) {

                var str = input[i].value;
                str.search("@");
                if (str.match("@")) {
                   emailaddress= str;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you define the `str` Variable?

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed that out! I'll edit my question and add it back in.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Is it giving any errors? Is it doing anything at all?

Comment: It's giving no response at all when I click submit.

Comment: I know that in it's current state, it shouldnt do anything, but if I add in an alert to make sure it's worked, still nothing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem with this code is that you have for (i = 0; i <= input.length; i++)  which attempts to go one pass the number of elements in the array. Get rid of the equals making it for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) and you should be fine.

Comment: No Problem, glad to help! Actually, I didn't notice the error till I pulled up a console and started typing stuff in to try it out. If you're not accustomed to doing so, you can try things out by hitting f12 in your favorite browser to bring up developer tools (my favorite is Chrome). The console also provides useful information when something goes wrong. I noticed you responded to Vacation9 saying it just failed, but when I did it in the Chrome console it told me that input[i].value was undefined. I then figured out that the reason it was undefined was because I was outside of my list.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try that! I need to get in the habit of using tools like that before I go zooming off to write my code!